# what should be transition in css3

Tags: css, flash, less, compass-sass

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         <!-- Need help in this css for transition of background-image -->
          body{
              -webkit-transition:background-image 5s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition:background-image 5s ease-in-out;
              -o-transition:background-image 5s ease-in-out;
              -ms-transition:background-image 5s ease-in-out;
               transition:background-image 5s ease-in-out;
            }
      </style>
    </head>
 <body>
</body>
</html>
```

[need a background-image transition like flash](http://www.bertozziepicure.com/)

Need  a flash background-image effect

I tried this too

```
   $('body').
        animate({ opacity: 0 }, 
                   'slow', 
                    function () {
                        $(this).css(
                           { 'background-image': 
                             'url(\''+jdata.imageurl+  '\')'    }).animate({ opacity: 1 });
                     });
```

Comment: $('body').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 'slow', function () {
                            $(this).css({ 'background-image': 'url(\'' + jsondata.imageurl+ '\')' }).animate({ opacity: 1 });
                        });

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to transition a background-image, transitions can only transition those properties which have an implicit, or explicit, numerical scale; for example such properties as `width`, `height`, `opacity` and so on.

This is the same reason that it's not possible to transition to, or from, `display: none` because there are two states (visible and non-visible) with no possible interim steps between the two.

If you want to transition between one background-image and another, you'd need to stack multiple elements in the same space and then fade the element(s) containing that background-image in/out using either CSS transitions or animations.

You could, alternatively, transition the `background-image-position` properties to give the impression of a carousel, for example, since this property uses CSS length units, which can – of course – be transitioned smoothly.

Comment: I can, but unless you can clearly explain the result you want - and, ideally, provide relevant HTML - it's hard to correct your provided code.

Comment: ok.. so i have seen in the given link http://www.bertozziepicure.com/ .. when i switch from one link to another there is transition with a flick of black surroundings..its pretty cool like dissolve effect